# Running Function Before and After Accessing Several JpaRepositories

Tags: java, spring, oop, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have several interfaces which annotated with @Repository and extends JpaRepository.
All of them are in same package in my project.

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerDTO>{
    List<CustomerDTO> findByKeyCustomerId(long customerId);
    List<CustomerDTO> findByKeyCustomerIdAndName(long customerId, String name);
}

@Repository
public interface UpdateRepository extends JpaRepository<UpdateDTO> {
  @Query(value = "select nextval('sq')", nativeQuery = true)
  Integer getNextUpdateId();
}
```

I use the methods of the repositories in many different places in different packages in my project in middle of the code.

```
customerRepository.findByKeyCustomerId(customerId);
customerRepository.save(customerEntry);
updateRepository.getNextUpdateId();
updateRepository.save(updateEntry);
```

I want to call the same method before all of these calls above and call another same method after these calls.

```
private void before(Span span) {
   span.annotate("Before");
}

private void after(Span span) {
   span.annotate("After");
}
```

I want to simulate the following code:

```
span.annotate("Before");
Integer updateId = updateRepository.getNextUpdateId(); //can be any other repository method
span.annotate("After");
```

How can I achieve that in generic way, without inserting before(span) and after(span) everywhere in code where I call the methods of repository interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a typical case where you can implement aspect oriented programming (AOP). If you are using spring boot then it would be very easy for you to implement it.
For a starter you can check this link :- https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-aop-with-spring-boot-starter-aop

You may have to tune it a bit to achieve what you are expecting. But seems doable.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I see that all the methods (=advices?) in this mechanism are not using any external variables, how can I pass parameter(=tracer or span)?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html
This can help you.
Check specifically "6.2.4.6.4. Proceeding with arguments" section